# Showing the menu bar on multiple screens on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors

I've just installed a new monitor on my MacBook, and I noticed that the menu bar only appears on one screen or the other - I have to haul over to whichever screen has the menu if I'm using the other one, and it's a pretty frustrating process. Does anyone know if there's a setting or utility that lets you display the menu bar on both screens?

Answer (score 2):

I used [Second Bar](http://blog.boastr.net/?page_id=1722) for a while.  It works on Snow Leopard and I didn't have any problems.

Comment: I'm seeing some issues on Mountain Lion. The windows beneath the second bar wiggles/jitters quite a bit when maximized. FYI for anyone reading this ...

Answer (score 1):

Well - In my experince you cannot have it on both.  Although, you can mirror your screen, but it defeats the purpose of two monitors, a.k.a: extended desktop. I would just move the menu bar to your primary monitor - use your macbook as the extended desktop - it's what I did with my iMac.  It sits to the left of my desk, while my main monitor is center and on a [Ergotron](http://www.ergotron.com/), so I can lower my viewing plane.

You can access this settings under Settings - Display, then Drag the menu bar to the monitor you want. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

http://homepage.mac.com/khsu/DejaMenu/DejaMenu.html - Its old now, but used to work well on Leopard ...

Answer (score 0):

Tested on macOS Ventura:

- System Settings > Desktop & Dock
- In the Mission Control section, enable "Displays have separate spaces"